# Fixed point set of a measurable map

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and  $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. If $f:X\rightarrow X$
is a measurable map, does it follow that the set of fixed points of $f$ is an element of $\Sigma$.

If this not true, what conditions on $X$ and $\Sigma$ can ensure this? Is this true, for example if we let $X$ be a (Hausdorff) topological space and $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$ algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Delta:=\{(x,x),x\in X\}\subset X^2$ and $\operatorname{Fix}(f):=\{x\in X,f(x)=x\}$. Assume that $\Delta \in\Sigma\otimes\Sigma$. Then defining $F(x):=(x,f(x))$ from $X$ to $X\times X$, and noticing that $\operatorname{Fix}(f)=F^{-1}(\Delta)$, we have that $\operatorname{Fix}(f)\in\Sigma$.

When $X$ is a second countable Hausdorff space, $\Delta$ is closed for the product topology (which is in this case the product of the Borel $\sigma$-algebras on $X$), hence $\operatorname{Fix}(f)$ is measurable.

Comment: I think the last sentence might be misleading. That $\Delta$ is in the product topology (which follows already from being Hausdorff) is not enough. You need second countability to get that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X^2$ equals the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel $\sigma$-algebras to make $F$ measurable.